# Defining where on the page the flowdocument I am printing will 'start' and 'end'

Tags: wpf, header, printing, flowdocument, spacing

I am almost done with implementing a printing functionality, but I am having trouble getting the last hurdle done with.

My problem is, that I am printing some reports, consisting of a header (with information about the person the report is about), a footer (with a page number) and the content in the middle, which is a FlowDocument. Since the flowdocuments can be fairly long, It is very possible that they will span multiple pages.

My approach is to make a custom FlowDocumentPaginator which derives from DocumentPaginator.

In there i define my header and my footer.

However, when I print my page, the flowdocument and my header and footer are on top of eachother.

So my question is plain and simple - how do I define from where and to where the flowdocument part on the pages will be placed?

here is the code from my custommade Paginator:

```
public class HeaderedFlowDocumentPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
    private DocumentPaginator flowDocumentpaginator;

    public HeaderedFlowDocumentPaginator(FlowDocument document)
    {
        flowDocumentpaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource) document).DocumentPaginator;
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid
    {
        get { return flowDocumentpaginator.IsPageCountValid; }
    }

    public override int PageCount
    {
        get { return flowDocumentpaginator.PageCount; }
    }

    public override Size PageSize
    {
        get { return flowDocumentpaginator.PageSize;  }
        set { flowDocumentpaginator.PageSize = value; }
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source
    {
        get { return flowDocumentpaginator.Source; }
    }

    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        DocumentPage page = flowDocumentpaginator.GetPage(pageNumber);

        ContainerVisual newVisual = new ContainerVisual();
        newVisual.Children.Add(page.Visual);

        DrawingVisual header = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dc = header.RenderOpen())
        {
            //Header data
        }
        newVisual.Children.Add(header);

        DrawingVisual footer = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dc = footer.RenderOpen())
        {
            Typeface typeface = new Typeface("Trebuchet MS");
            FormattedText text = new FormattedText("Page " + (pageNumber + 1).ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, 14, Brushes.Black);

            dc.DrawText(text, new Point(page.Size.Width - 100, page.Size.Height-30));
        }

        newVisual.Children.Add(footer);

        DocumentPage newPage = new DocumentPage(newVisual);
        return newPage;
    }
}
```

And here is the printdialogue call:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(<My string of text - RTF formatted>));

            TextRange tr = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
            tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);

            stream.Close();
            fd.ColumnWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;

            HeaderedFlowDocumentPaginator paginator = new HeaderedFlowDocumentPaginator(fd);

            printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "myReport");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it myself - there is a function called pagepadding, where I can set the distance from the four sides of the paper :)

Fairly easy solution - I just didn't know what to look for

Example:

```
Flowdocument fd = new FlowDocument();

fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(0.25,160,0.25,45);
```